# Linearity of convergence in probability

Tags: probability, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove the following statement. Let $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$, both in probability. Then $aX_n + bY_n \rightarrow aX + bY$ in probability for  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a,b \neq 0$.

The statement I need to prove is
$$\forall{\varepsilon} >0 \qquad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P\{\lvert aX_n + bY_n - aX - bY \rvert > \varepsilon\} = 0$$

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Note that
$$\lvert aX_n + bY_n - aX - bY \rvert \leq \lvert a\rvert\lvert X_n - X\rvert + \lvert b\rvert\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert$$
Therefore
$$P\{\lvert aX_n + bY_n - aX - bY \rvert > \varepsilon\} \leq P\{\lvert a\rvert\lvert X_n - X\rvert + \lvert b\rvert\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert > \varepsilon\}$$

Here comes the part which I feel uncomfortable about.

$$P\{\lvert a\rvert\lvert X_n - X\rvert + \lvert b\rvert\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert > \varepsilon\} = P\{\lvert a\rvert\lvert X_n - X\rvert \vee \lvert b\rvert\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}$$
Now I let $n$ go to infinity and claim that the RHS goes to $0$. I base this claim on the intuition that $\lvert X_n - X\rvert$ and $\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert$ converge in probability to $0$. Therefore their "worst case" combination must do the same.

Could someone help me fix this proof or post a better one? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z_n=|a||X_n-X|$ and $W_n=|b||Y_n-Y|$. Then, a quick argument by contradiction gives
$$
Z_n+W_n>\varepsilon\implies Z_n>\varepsilon/2\text{ or }W_n>\varepsilon/2
$$
which implies
$$
\Pr(Z_n+W_n>\varepsilon)\leq\Pr[(Z_n>\varepsilon/2)\cup(W_n>\varepsilon/2)]\leq\Pr(Z_n>\varepsilon/2)+\Pr(W_n>\varepsilon/2).
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, the rightmost expression goes to $0$. So the same must hold for the leftmost expression.